# xml parsing in go with repetitive tags

Tags: xml, go, struct, slice

When an xml feed has multiple tags within a structure I am having issues parsing it:

```
<feed>
<entry>
:
:
</entry>
<entry>
:
:

</entry>
</feed>
```

In this case I have no issues parsing the entry by defining an array of []entries
However one of the entries is a geocode tag which has valuename and value tag repeated twice.  How does one define a structure in such a case.?

```
<geocode>
<valueName>abc</valueName>
<value>a1</value>
<valueName>def</valueName>
<value>d1</value>
</geocode>
```

Here is the go program that I am having issues with
https://play.golang.org/p/SE8RXTNbYl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have multiple tags with the same name under the same parent tag, you can always use a slice which will hold all the occurrences of the tag, regardless if they are enumerated next to each other or there are other tags between them.

To be complete, this is the XML fragment you want to parse:

```
<cap:geocode>
    <valueName>FIPS6</valueName>
    <value>002090 002290</value>
    <valueName>UGC</valueName>
    <value>AKZ222</value>
</cap:geocode>
```

So simply change your `geocode` struct from this:

```
type geocode struct {
    ValueName1 string `xml:"valueName"`
    Value1     string `xml:"value"`
    ValueName2 string `xml:"valueName"`
    Value2     string `xml:"value"`
}
```

To this:

```
type geocode struct {
    ValueNames []string `xml:"valueName"`
    Values     []string `xml:"value"`
}
```

And code to print them:

```
gc := v.Entries[0].Geocode
log.Println(len(gc.Values))
log.Println(gc.ValueNames)
log.Println(gc.Values)
for i := range gc.Values {
    fmt.Printf("ValueName=%s, Value=%s\n", gc.ValueNames[i], gc.Values[i])
}
```

Output (try your modified source on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QrCDmgVyrY)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 2
2009/11/10 23:00:00 [FIPS6 UGC]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 [002090 002290 AKZ222]
ValueName=FIPS6, Value=002090 002290
ValueName=UGC, Value=AKZ222
```